# How to link Boost.Python to a program?

Tags: python, c++, boost, cmake, compilation

Good day!

```cpp
#include <boost/python.hpp>

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    boost::python::exec("print('Hello!')");
    return 0;
}
```

```
...
find_package(Boost COMPONENTS python)
find_package(Python COMPONENTS Development)

include_directories(${Python_INCLUDE_DIRS} ${Boost_INCLUDE_DIR})
target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} ${Python_LIBRARIES} ${Boost_LIBRARIES})
```

The error:

- undefined reference to `_*imp__ZN5boost6python4execEPKcNS0_3api6objectES4*'

If I am trying to link Python without Boost, it works. By the way, other functions of Boost.Python also are not linked.

Python 3.10.2, CMake 3.21.1, compiled Boost via MinGW 8.1.0 64-bit and use this tool to compile my program.

Where do I mistake? Thanks.

Comment: Are you sure it's finding Boost? Missing components are **not** an error. You're using a fairly old CMake, it might not support finding Boost::Python nicely (I remember there were issues, not what they were). In a pinch, set `Boost_NO_BOOST_CMAKE`  to `ON` so that Boost's Config module is ignored.

Comment: Other Boost componets such as tests are found with no problem.

Comment: set(Boost_NO_BOOST_CMAKE ON) gives no effect.

Comment: Tryied to compile Boost.Python via other compilator (MSVC 17). There is still the error.

Comment: CMake 3.5 is just really, really old, so I have no comparison material. In current CMake, `Boost_PYTHON_LIBRARIES` is **also** set (to `Boost::python`). So you might look for that variable in `CMakeCache.txt` or elsewhere, or try `cmake --trace-source=FindBoost.cmake` to see what it's doing internally.

Comment: @AdriaandeGroot, Boost_PYTHON_LIBRARY_DEBUG:STRING=D:/Boost/lib/libboost_python310-mgw8-mt-d-x64-1_78.a
Boost_PYTHON_LIBRARY_RELEASE:STRING=D:/Boost/lib/libboost_python310-mgw8-mt-x64-1_78.a

They exist there.

Maybe I compiled it wrong?

Comment: @AdriaandeGroot, I clarified CMake 3.21.1. The minimum was just that but changing to 3.21 does not help.

Comment: Try `target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} Boost::python)` then, using the imported target rather than the variable. That's the "modern CMake" approach. But this is out of my depth, since I don't have CMake- or Boost-on-Windows experience to speak of.

Comment: I had seen Boost_PYTHON_LIBRARIES was Boost::python but your way I tried too, it didn't help. Will try on Linux.